# DXA 1.7 Java.lang.RuntimeException: Not possible to retrieve the dynamic configuration

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-1.7

I have installed DXA 1.7 (.Net) on SDL Web 8.5. I have managed to setup a fully functional Staging Content Delivery Server including Session Preview. But I'm running into issues on the Live Content Delivery Server. If I browse to the DXA homepage I get the following error:

> 2017-06-23 14:40:51,693 [25] ERROR - Failed to execute query
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ServiceQueryException: Failed to execute query ---> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceClientException: {"error":{"code":"9000","message":"java.lang.RuntimeException: Not possible to retrieve the dynamic configuration"}}
>      at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery()
>      at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)

[image]

Apart from this error which is also logged by the Content Service, no other error is logged. The same error is logged in the `site.log` from the DXA website

I have checked the following:

1. Whether the Context service is accessible with Postman
2. Whether the Topology is correct
3. Whether the web capability element is present in the `cd_storage_conf.xml` of the `cd_storage_conf.xml`

Any ideas?

Cheers,

Gert

Comment: How does the stack trace in the Content Service log look?

Comment: @RickPannekoek see the following [link] https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pdx7i2321j4s72p/AAAPHAeyjro_cxCGw5sGSNZOa?dl=0)

Answer (score 2):

It appears that there were few problems with the linking of Base URL's in the discovery database which was causing this issue. 
It could not be identified why this inconsistencies in the DB, which should have been resolved by syncing (overwriting) from Topology side. After running the following queries the issue was resolved:

```
delete from CONFIGURATION_VALUE where ITEM_ID = '799a1e02-78e4-449d-
916f-f78e62021be0'; 
delete from CONFIGURATION_VALUE where ITEM_ID = 'efe93f0f-6f25-4997-
8891-97a80ab85a8d'; 
delete from CONFIGURATION_ITEM where ID = '799a1e02-78e4-449d-916f-
f78e62021be0'; 
delete from CONFIGURATION_ITEM where ID = 'efe93f0f-6f25-4997-8891-
97a80ab85a8d'; 
insert into CONFIGURATION_ITEMS_LINKS values 
('dev_xxxxxx_RootWebApp','a5dfb56c-b492-46a5-8db4-
1caa808a1f66');
```

Comment: I believe the following url informs us of how to get these queries:
https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000005260  I used these and it fixed the issue.  I didn't have to perform any inserts.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error few times in our environment, but is very difficult to reproduce again.
Restart your content micro service and recycle your dxa app pool.It will start to work again.

Update : Please check the following link to see if there is any difference in your discovery service Web Capability between Staging and Live environment setup,
[code:9000 error message in SDL Web8 environment](https://gateway.sdl.com/communityknowledge?articleName=NullPointerException-occurs-on-DXA-1-5-website-error-when-accessed-in-distributed-Web-8-1-setup)

Comment: Hi Rajesh, thanks for your reply. I did flush the app pool. I even reinstalled the services. Are you sure you got the same error: "Not possible to retrieve the dynamic configuration"?

Comment: I think, it is the discovery service configuration for Live environment which is causing this issue(I have updated my answer and added a link which discuss about similar issue). Please cross check the discovery.svc address in your live DXA Website for  right microservice address and has OAuth user credentials

Comment: I also found this link and I have double checked that the webcapability element is present in both the cd_storage_conf.xml and in the discovery database. I also double checked if the correct ttm-websites ids are registered in the discovery database. Is there a way to get more logging other than the Java runtime error?

Comment: @GertdeHeul did you try updating the discovery registration `java -jar discovery-registration.jar update`

Comment: @BartKoopman, yes both update and sync